# how to execute set of statements dynamically when year changes in my sql

Tags: mysql

i have a table to generate auto increment number its name is

`table1_seq`

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

it will start from and increment by one for every insert

what i want is can i reset this  `table1_seq` to again from 1 when year changes i.e 2019 to 2020.
i have seen in tutorial that it says

> you cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used.

so here as per my knowledge when year changes we have to truncate the table table1_seq and set auto increment to 1

can we do it by dynamically when year changes by triggers or events or with another technique please do help me

thank you.

Comment: Drop the table and recreate it when the year changes, The counter will reset. Your trigger would be on the insert event for the table that uses the counter. Check the date at that point.

Comment: yes can you please help me how to do it problematically when year changes.

Comment: @scaisEdge can you please tell how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your logic.

For example:

1) There is no guarantee that your record will come on 1st `2020-01-01 00:00:00` or `2020-01-01 23:00:00` OR `2020-01-31 00:00:00`

2) Because of this it becomes difficult to set truncate based on insert.

3) Another problem is that trigger will fire at every insert, for a event that needs to be performed once every year. This will result to increase in number of transaction per query.

Here, I would recommend `event_scheduler` or `cron` which will run the truncate the table on `2020-01-01 00:00:00`

1) Solution(`event_scheduler`)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT truncate_table1_seq
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
    DO BEGIN
        TRUNCATE table1_seq;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

By Default scheduler is not turned on you have run the below command.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

2) Solution(cron)

Step 1: `crontab -e` run command on your linux terminal.

Step 2: `0 0 1 1 * /usr/bin/mysql --user=[user_name] --password=[password] [db_name] < /home/[user]/recurring-job.sql` copy the command & paste it.

Hit `ctrl-X` and type “Yes” to save and exit.

Where [username] & [password] is your mysql username password. create a file recurring-job.sql and paste your query  `TRUNCATE table1_seq;`

Comment: can i check this by changing data and time of my computer to 2020-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Why change computer date and time, you change event scheduler date and time

Comment: yes its working i have checked foe Every 1 minute. thank you very much @ Rahul Singh

Comment: can i have your insta ?